# How to manage raw data (bitstream or bytestream) in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, io

My C# .NET 4.0 application needs to access data in the filesystem and access them as a bitstream or bytestream. What I need is the following:

- Splitting a data block into two sequential data blocks.
- Merging two datablocks by attaching one to the other.
- Access bytes or bits.
- Storing the data block in the filesystem.
- Loading a data block from the filesystem.

That's it. What is the best practice to do this in .NET 4.0?

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried the Stream API, in particular FileStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start reading this: [C# Input/Output Classes Simplified](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/08/05/io.html?page=5)